# DomSanitizer and viewContainerRef break SSR

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

I have a Angular Universal App (Version 5.0.2) using a dynamic component loader for rendering the page. It uses the `viewContainerRef` to catch/clear and create the components.

It works fine inside the Browser, but the Server throws an error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[ViewContainerRef]: 
StaticInjectorError[ViewContainerRef]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
```

For some external HTML I have to use `DomSanitizer` to `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()`

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[DomSanitizer]: 
StaticInjectorError[DomSanitizer]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for DomSanitizer!
```

I know they don't have to be added to some Provider (I think it was changed back then with Version 4 or before)

- Does anybody know how to fix this problem or know that it worked before Version 5 (then I could report a bug)?
- *or* is it not even possible because `DomSanitizer` and `viewContainerRef` don't work on `platform-server`?

Comment: I'm not sure if we have the same issue but I am getting the same error from a library that uses DomSanitizer.  It worked before Angular 5, now it does not.  I am not using a Universal App.